# std::function< void ( const A & )> can't cast to std::function< void ( const B & ) > when B inherits from A

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently trying to store some listeners in a std::vector, and call them when needed.
I have the following definitions in the base class:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A();
    typedef std::function< void( const A & ) > Listener;
    std::vector< Listener > listeners;
    void addListener( const Listener & listener)
    {
        this->listeners.push_back( listener );
    }
}
```

I have a simple B class:

```
class B : public A
{
    virtual ~B();
}
```

All I want to do is be able to write a call like this:

```
B b;
b.addListener( [] ( const & B ) { /* Do something */ } );
```

But this doesn't compile, with the following error:

```
error: no viable conversion from '<lambda at main.cpp:158:27>' to 'const Listener' (aka 'const function<void (const A &)>')
```

I am currently avoiding this issue with `dynamic_cast`, but it seems a bad thing, or a bad design to me…

Comment: It is a bad thing as you will call the `B` listener from `A` (which may be not a `B`).

Comment: Indeed, it is just enforced by the fact that I know what listener I've added to the list… But it is a weak check

Comment: C++ type system is rather primitive by modern standards. If you want a language that supports covariance and contravariance, you have to fing a different language.

Comment: "Your solution is in another language" is NOT a possibility. The software I'm writing is already using C++.

Comment: Meanwhile, you may want to consider CRTP. If listeners in class A accept A and listeners in class B accept B, then A inherits something like `ListenerSet<A>` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider normal functions first. Just because `A` and `B` are related types and you can cast between them, that doesn't mean that the types of the functions `void f(const A&)` and `void g(const B&)` are related, and pointers to those functions are not convertible to each other.

Similarly, `SomeTemplate<A>` and `SomeTemplate<B>` are not related types and cannot be converted to each other.

I hope now it makes sense that `std::function<void(const A&)>` and `std::function(void(const A&)>` are unrelated types and not convertible back and forth between each other.

Comment: Now if the standard specified a way to make a ref-argument in-only/out-only, we could have co-variant/contra-variant input-types, and not only covariant return-types.

Comment: That put some more light to my knowledge, thanks. I'm afraid I don't know how to handle this "listener pattern" correctly…

Comment: A `std::function<void(const A&)>` *is* convertible to `std::function<void(const B&)>` if `const B&` can be converted to `const A&`, but not the reverse.

Comment: @T.C. yes, you can construct `std::function<void(const A&)>` from the other, but it's just wrapping it, which while technically that means `is_convertible` returns true, it's not because the types are related in any way. I'll clarify the last sentence of the answer

Comment: gah, I meant vice versa